# In Newtonsoft JSON, how can I fall back to the default conversion behaviour/temporarily disable a JSON converter

Tags: .net, json, converters, json.net

I am attempting to deserialize some JSON.

Some of the things in the JSON use a custom JSONConverter. This converter looks up the previous version of the object and merges in changes from the JSON. However, this behaviour makes no sense when the object is new (because there is no previous version), which I check by inspecting the id.

Is there a way to temporarily disable this converter or fall back to the default behaviour from inside the ReadJson method?

The obvious way would be to remove the converter from the JsonSerializer and then call Deserialize again with that, but this has the problem that none of the subsequent items will then use the custom converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My work around for this was to add some state for excluded types to the converter, and to then test this in the CanConvert method.